# jQuery UI sortable events fires multiple times

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm working with one project and it's based on jQuery UI Sortable and Draggable. 
The problem is that sortable events being fired multiple times. (I used search).

There is the JS:

```
$('.column_inner').sortable({
    item: '.element',
    revert: 'invalid',
    helper: 'original',
    handle: '.drag_handle',
    dropOnEmpty: true,
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    forceHelperSize: false,
    appendTo: "body",
    connectWith: '.column_inner',
    receive: function(event, ui) {
        //Got the item and if it new inserting it from database.
    },
    update: function(event, ui) {
        //Saving sorting in to database
    },
    change: function(event, ui)
    {
        //This one fires multiple times, over does the same.
    },
    stop: function()
    {
        //This one fires only at stop
    }
});
```

There is HTML:

```
<div class="row" id="row_115">
    <div class="column size_3" rel="1">
        <div class="column_inner">
            <div id="element_23" class="element editable">
                This is element
                <span class="drag_handle control_icon">Handle</span>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <span class="up">UP</span> <span class="down">DOWN</span>
</div>

<div class="row" id="row_117">
    <div class="column size_half" rel="1">
        <div class="column_inner">
            <div id="element_20" class="element editable">
                Another element<br />
                <span class="drag_handle control_icon">Handle</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column size_half" rel="2">
        <div class="column_inner">
            <div id="element_20" class="element editable">
                Third element<br />
                <span class="drag_handle control_icon">Handle</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <span class="up">UP</span> <span class="down">DOWN</span>
</div>
```

What I did wrong? Why events fires multiple times?

Comment: 'change' event will fire each time the DOM position of the elements in the sortable changes while sorting. Could you please explain it in detail or give the scenario in which the events are getting fired ?

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong.  This is a more complicated plugin and you just have to program taking into account how it works.  So instead of looking at "change" firing multiple times as a problem, just step through it and see that it's firing for every DOM change.  Then just adapt your code to take that into account.

Comment: Change event should be fires each time DOM position changes. But as I checked placeholder disappearing somehow and without any change just start change count gets increased to xx times. Even if I move element just for one pixel.

Comment: The thing is that, normally you not see that placeholder is disappearing but I checked with firebug and I can see it does...

Comment: Will have to look at your working code. Can you provide a jsfiddle with your working code ?